# Nuget packages not visible: Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Crazy thing here, I can't see *some* `nuget` packages in file explorer.  I'm using `Windows 8` and `Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate`.  My co-workers can see all the packages on their `Windows 7` machines.  I've got file explorer configured to show all files.

For example, I can't see proprietary packages or `Automapper`.  To make it even crazier, `Automapper` works fine, but my solution won't build because it can't find the proprietary packages.  Source Control Explorer in TFS says I have the latest of everything, but not according the file explorer.

What's going on here?  Is this by design?

Comment: Can you give some details about how your solution and projects are organized? A high level view ...

Answer (score 0):

There was a disconnect between my machine and TFS.  I had to delete the solution folder using file explorer, remap, and do a "get latest".  But this wasn't enough, I had to do a "Get Specific Version" and force a full restore.  Everything good after that.